# Create reusable processing logic on top of predefined blocks with TPL dataflow?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, tpl-dataflow

I love TPL dataflow.

Well, an interesting design choice is that, most predefined block use Delegates to allow us to implement processing logic. That looks good in simple scenarios. But let's think about real world big applications, which requires modularity and encapsulation. I found it hard and unnatural to write well structured app with the DELEGATE approach.

For example, if what I want is just a `MultiplyIntByTwoTransformBlock` and a `NoOpActionBlock` as a reusable class TYPE (not an instance). How do I achieve it? I wish I can inherit from `TransformBlock`/`ActionBlock` and say, override some `Process()` method to achieve this. But predefined blocks are sealed. They only accept delegates.

I know I can create a custom block from scratch but obviously it is too complex for me because what I need is just a little customization on top of the predefined ones.

So, how do I achieve my goal?

UPDATE: 
I am not saying there are things delegates cannot do. I am saying exposing abstract blocks in template method pattern is better in many scenarios. Say, I wish I can write a AbstractMultiplyBlock and MultiplyByTwoBlock and MultiplyByThreeBlock, taking advantage of polymorphism. Delegates, unfortunately does not provide such kind of data&logic reusability.

Comment: BTW, your `NoOpActionBlock` pretty much already exists as [`DataflowBlock.NullTarget()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462765).

Comment: Yes. I found the wonderful NullTarget() method after I posted my question. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: The design choice to follow a functional style instead of traditional OO in TPL Dataflow was very deliberate. It's no accident that most libraries and even _languages_ that specialize in the Actor pattern take this approach. It's a natural fit. I don't think you're sacrificing reuse or encapsulation at all if you do it right, and you can use objects all day _inside_  your blocks.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any reason why you would need custom block *types* for that. Helper methods should be enough:

```
public static IPropagatorBlock<int, int> CreateMultiplyIntTransformBlock(
    int multiplier)
{
    return new TransformBlock<int, int>(i => i * multiplier);
}

public static IPropagatorBlock<int, int> CreateMultiplyIntByTwoTransformBlock()
{
    return CreateMultiplyIntTransformBlock(2);
}
```

If you think that a delegate isn't enough for you, then maybe you're trying to put your logic in the wrong place. There is no reason why the delegate can't use objects that use encapsulation and modularity properly. This way, your application logic stays separate from the logic of executing the code.

But if you really wanted to do what you're asking about, you could do that by encapsulating a `TransformBlock` in a custom class that implements `IPropgatorBlock` and also has your abstract `Process()` method. But doing that properly is somewhat complicated, have a look at [Guide to Implementing Custom TPL Dataflow Blocks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/05/10244302.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks svick. The helper function you gave works. But still it is exposing an instance, not a type. Delegates are ACTIONs inside blocks and I don't want it to be exposed to the outside, say, the pipeline class which links blocks together.

Comment: I am not saying there are things delegates cannot do. I am saying exposing abstract blocks in template method pattern is better in many scenarios. Say, I wish I can write a AbstractMultiplyBlock and MultiplyByTwoBlock and MultiplyByThreeBlock, taking advantage of polymorphism. Delegates, unfortunately does not provide such kind of data&logic reusability. Thanks.

Comment: @Dodd I still don't see why would you need types for that, you can have that kind of reusability with delegates too, see edit. And if you want to use polymorphism, you can call a polymorphic method of another type from your delegate. E.g. `AbstractMultiplicator multiplicator = new MultiplicateByTwo(); var block = new TransformBlock<int, int>(i => multiplicator.Multiplicate(i));`. I think this way gives you better separation of concerns.

Comment: Your AbstractMultiplicator makes sense to me, svick. Bascially we move processors out of block and reference/capture them inside delegate. Although the reason for delegate-design-choice is still unknown, your sample works pretty well and we do get polymorphism. +1 for your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @svick, sorry to dig up this old thread but as I mentioned in another answer, now there is a library [DataflowEx](https://github.com/gridsum/dataflowex) that handles the problem (and more). As you are a master of TPL Dataflow, it will be great if you take some time to help review the library. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4):

Now there is a open source library, [DataflowEx](https://github.com/gridsum/dataflowex), which is particularliy designed to solve this problem. In addition, it provides more features to help construct and represent a dataflow graph.

Disclaimer: I am the author of DataflowEx. It is created to answer my own question. Hope it also helps others :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an abstract type that implements the same interfaces as the target block type (`TransformBlock` implements `IPropagatorBlock` and `IReceivableSourceBlock`).

Instead of duplicating that block's behavior, delegate all method calls to an `innerBlock` of that type.

```
public abstract class AbstractMultiplyBlock<TInput, TOutput>
    : IPropagatorBlock<TInput, TOutput>, IReceivableSourceBlock<TOutput>
{
    private readonly TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput> innerBlock;

    protected AbstractMultiplyBlock(TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput> innerBlock)
    {
        this.innerBlock = innerBlock;
    }

    // ... interface implementations omitted for brevity, see appendix
}
```

---

This abstract class has all the same properties and methods as the `TransformBlock` class. Now, create derived types that pass an instance of `TransformBlock` to the base constructor.

```
public sealed class MultiplyByTwoBlock : AbstractMultiplyBlock<int, int>
{
    public MultiplyByTwoBlock()
        : base(new TransformBlock<int, int>(x => x * 2))
    {
    }
}

public sealed class MultiplyByThreeBlock : AbstractMultiplyBlock<int, int>
{
    public MultiplyByThreeBlock()
        : base(new TransformBlock<int, int>(x => x * 3))
    {
    }
}
```

---

Usage is the same as with any other instance of `TransformBlock`

```
var calculator1 = new MultiplyByTwoBlock();
var calculator2 = new MultiplyByThreeBlock();
calculator1.LinkTo(calculator2);

// x = 10 * 2 * 3
calculator1.Post(10);
var x = calculator2.Receive();
```

---

**Appendix**

Full source code for `AbstractMultiplyBlock`

```
public abstract class AbstractMultiplyBlock<TInput, TOutput>
    : IPropagatorBlock<TInput, TOutput>, IReceivableSourceBlock<TOutput>
{
    private readonly TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput> innerBlock;

    protected AbstractMultiplyBlock(TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput> innerBlock)
    {
        this.innerBlock = innerBlock;
    }

    public DataflowMessageStatus OfferMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, TInput messageValue, ISourceBlock<TInput> source,
        bool consumeToAccept)
    {
        return ((ITargetBlock<TInput>)innerBlock).OfferMessage(messageHeader, messageValue, source, consumeToAccept);
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        innerBlock.Complete();
    }

    public void Fault(Exception exception)
    {
        ((IDataflowBlock)innerBlock).Fault(exception);
    }

    public Task Completion
    {
        get { return innerBlock.Completion; }
    }

    public IDisposable LinkTo(ITargetBlock<TOutput> target, DataflowLinkOptions linkOptions)
    {
        return innerBlock.LinkTo(target, linkOptions);
    }

    public TOutput ConsumeMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<TOutput> target, out bool messageConsumed)
    {
        return ((ISourceBlock<TOutput>)innerBlock).ConsumeMessage(messageHeader, target, out messageConsumed);
    }

    public bool ReserveMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<TOutput> target)
    {
        return ((ISourceBlock<TOutput>)innerBlock).ReserveMessage(messageHeader, target);
    }

    public void ReleaseReservation(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<TOutput> target)
    {
        ((ISourceBlock<TOutput>)innerBlock).ReleaseReservation(messageHeader, target);
    }

    public bool TryReceive(Predicate<TOutput> filter, out TOutput item)
    {
        return innerBlock.TryReceive(filter, out item);
    }

    public bool TryReceiveAll(out IList<TOutput> items)
    {
        return innerBlock.TryReceiveAll(out items);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example Steven. This works gracefully. There is a bit performance concern on 'delegate all method calls to an innerBlock', though.

Comment: Btw, I created a library called [DataflowEx](https://github.com/gridsum/dataflowex) to solve my problem. It took a similiar approach but the outer class implmenets IDataflow (a new interface representing a dataflow **graph**) rather than IDataflowBlock. You may take a look if interested.

Comment: Couldn't you make `IDataflow` extend `IDataflowBlock`? That way, you could treat an entire graph as a block.

Comment: In DataflowEx design, you CAN have a IDataflow that only contains one block. The reason why IDataflow doesn't extend IDataflowBlock is simply that, IDataflow often represents many blocks and this inheritance may confuse user. Well, on the other hand, this doesn't cause a problem. Right? :)

Comment: I was just thinking that you might want to build dataflow networks of dataflow networks. Can't do that unless you can create `IDataflow` objects that recursively reference other `IDataflow` objects.

Comment: The real reason why I'm asking is because `IDataflow` duplicates the methods in `IDataflowBlock` instead of re-using them.

Comment: So the idea would be to treat an entire graph as a single block.

Comment: Well understood. But is there any solid benefit to reuse IDataflowBlock? DataflowEx provides IDataflow as the graph handle because 1) it is designed for graph 2)its name is semantically better 3) we take control of it 4) easier to understand: IDataflow and IDataflowBlock are on different level.

Comment: I'm just saying that the `IDataflow` interface can inherit the `IDataflowBlock` interface. There's no reason NOT to do it that I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

My custom blocks so far have been written simply as a bunch of factory methods that use `DataflowBlock.Encapsulate` (if that's even needed).

So for a simple extension of TransformBlock that returns the same item that is passed to it, it would look something like this:

```
public static class MutatorBlock {
    public static TransformBlock<T, T> New<T>(Action<T> action, ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions options) {
        return new TransformBlock<T, T>(
            input => {
                action(input);
                return input;
            }, options);
    }
}
```

To instantiate this class, you use `MutatorBlock.New(...)` instead of `new MutatorBlock(...)`, but otherwise, there's not much difference.

I guess what I'm wondering is, what exactly do you need a type for? Inheritance won't work, sure, but composition still does. Could you maybe give an example where this is a major issue?